# I can't put data type from html into mysql with php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to put input data type from HTML into MySQL database but it doesn't work. When I push the submit button, it alerts fail.

I'm using phpMyAdmin and Apache with Bitnami and using Atom editor. When I echo the $reset_btday_input on the web, the result that I want and also fits for MySQL DATA type (like 2019-01-30) but the query doesn't work. 
Database table structure : id varchar(16), pw varchar(16), name varchar(10), btday date default NULL

SignIn.php

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
session_start();
?>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="SignInForm">
    <div class="SignInFormContents">

      <form action="SignInProgress.php" method="post">
        <fieldset class="inputs">
        <label>ID</label><input type="text" name="id_input" pattern="[a-zA-z0-9]{6,12}" required><br>
        <label>PW</label><input type="password" name="pw_input" pattern="[a-zA-z0-9]{6,12}" required><br>
        <label>NAME</label><input type="text" name="name_input" required><br>
        <label>BIRTHDAY</label><input type="date" name="btday_input"><br>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="buttons">


        <input type="submit" name="submit_signin" value="SIGN IN">
        <input type="reset" name="reset_form" value="RESET">
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

SignInProgress.php

```
<?php
  include 'default.php';

  $id_input = $_POST['id_input'];
  $pw_input = $_POST['pw_input'];
  $name_input = $_POST['name_input'];
  date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Seoul');
  $btday_input = strtotime($_POST['btday_input']);
  $reset_btday_input = date('Y-m-d', $btday_input);
  echo $reset_btday_input;

  $sql = "insert into signin values('$id_input', '$pw_input', '$name_input', '$reset_btday_input')";
  $result = $connect->query($sql);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

  if($row){
    echo "<script>alert('Success');</script>";
  }else{
    echo "<script>alert('Fail');</script>";
  }
?>
```

default.php

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "MY_ID", "MY_PASSWORD");
mysqli_select_db($connect, "MY_DB_NAME");

session_start();
?>
```

When I select 2019-01-30 on HTML form, "echo $reset_btday_input"'s result is 2019-01-30 on web. I'm sorry that my English sentences aren't very good. Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: Print out the resulting query and see if it works in phpMyAdmin or the likes. Also, is that the correct syntax for `INSERT INTO`? Shouldn't there be columns? `INSERT INTO tbl_name (col1,col2) VALUES(15,col1*2);`

Comment: @H.Kwon: you insert in wrong way.
       
Insert Into table name( " ", " ", " "); and any errors you are getting can you display that errors what you are getting.

Comment: @kerbholz @Asiya hold on. I tried it again with the same codes above and it worked. The query wasn't the problem I think `if($row){
    echo "<script>alert('Success');</script>";
  }else{
    echo "<script>alert('Fail');</script>";
  }` here is the problem

Answer (score 0):

@H.Kwon:firstly, you have to create values in query

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table name` WHERE `something`='{$something}'";
```

something it means what you wnat to fetch in your database then insert your values